# Simplifying Hide Show Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, hide, show

I've always coded my hide and show jQuery functions in a particular way, but I think that I could write them better.

Below is a filter where I view and hide different images within a portfolio.

HTML

```
   <div class="filters">
            <a id="all" class="active"><label>All Projects</label></a>
            <a id="branding"><label>Branding</label></a>
            <a id="websites"><label>Websites</label></a>
            <a id="digital"><label>Digital and Print</label></a>
            <a id="motion"><label>Motion Graphics</label></a>
            <a id="photography"><label>photography</label></a>
        </div>
```

JQUERY

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#all").click(function() {
      $("#all").addClass("active");
      $("#branding, #websites, #digital, #motion, #photography").removeClass("active");
    $(".all").show();
  });

  $("#branding").click(function() {
    $(".branding").show();

      $("#branding").addClass("active");
      $("#all, #websites, #digital, #motion, #photography").removeClass("active");
    $(".websites, .digital, .motion, .photography").hide();
  });


  $("#websites").click(function() {
    $(".websites").show();

      $("#websites").addClass("active");
      $("#branding, #all, #digital, #motion, #photography").removeClass("active");
    $(".digital, .branding, .motion, .photography").hide();
  });

  $("#digital").click(function() {
    $(".digital").show();
      
      $("#digital").addClass("active");
      $("#branding, #websites, #all, #motion, #photography").removeClass("active");
    $(".branding, .websites, .motion, .photography").hide();
  });

   $("#motion").click(function() {
    $(".motion").show();
      
      $("#motion").addClass("active");
      $("#branding, #websites, #all, #digital, #photography").removeClass("active");
    $(".branding, .websites, .photography").hide();
   });

    $("#photography").click(function() {
    $(".photography").show();
      
      $("#photography").addClass("active");
      $("#branding, #websites, #all, #digital").removeClass("active");
    $(".branding, .websites").hide();
  });
});
```

I reference the code from here code https://codepen.io/3be894d6-0f8e-489a-ae28-476df53bc557/pen/QXdjVJ.

Comment: Your jQuery code has classes that are not defined in the posted html code. please post correct code.

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur Where ? I don't see those classes in the html posted

Comment: i think he means .all, .branding and all the other classes where .Show() is called on. In your codepen environment you have extra html that is not in this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you require you can use common classes to group the elements by behaviour. Then you can add a single event handler to all those elements. Within that event handler you can separate the behaviour by using a `data` attribute to control the content which should be displayed when the elements are clicked, something like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.trigger').on('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let trigger = e.currentTarget;
    let target = trigger.dataset.target;
    if (target === '#all') {
      $('.trigger').removeClass('active');
      $('.content').add(trigger).addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.content, .trigger').removeClass('active')
        .filter(target).add(trigger).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
a.active { color: #C00; }
.content { display: none; }
.content.active { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
  <a href="#" class="trigger active" data-target="#all"><label>All Projects</label></a>
  <a href="#" class="trigger" data-target="#branding"><label>Branding</label></a>
  <a href="#" class="trigger" data-target="#websites"><label>Websites</label></a>
  <a href="#" class="trigger" data-target="#digital"><label>Digital and Print</label></a>
  <a href="#" class="trigger" data-target="#motion"><label>Motion Graphics</label></a>
  <a href="#" class="trigger" data-target="#photography"><label>Photography</label></a>
</div>

<div class="content active" id="branding">Branding</div>
<div class="content active" id="websites">Websites</div>
<div class="content active" id="digital">Digital</div>
<div class="content active" id="motion">Motion</div>
<div class="content active" id="photography">Photography</div>
```

Comment: What does the `jQuery($ => {});` function do?

Comment: It's the ES6 variant of `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {});`

Comment: Is it redundant if the jQuery is at the bottom of the DOM?

Comment: Yes, the same as any form of document load event handler would be.

Comment: Done. I've just noticed though that if i add more than 1 ID on to the div i want to show it doesn't appear anymore? Like so

Comment: <a href="#" class="work__item overlay content active" id="websites branding">

Comment: It's because that's not valid HTML. You can only have 1 id per element, and those id values must be unique.

Comment: ah ok, makes sense. Thanks